# Extracting Paragraphs with Headings from text files

Tags: python, regex, text, data-extraction

i have a text file somthing like this

```
  Summary 

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Sampler

 is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)
```

i used code that extracts paragraphs with summary title but could'nt Get with Title. 
i use code below, i need output as a text file with summary Title included.

```
import os

with open("se.txt", encoding='latin-1')as infile,open("fgh.txt",'w', encoding='latin-1')as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Summary":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "Sampler":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

i get output as

```
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

where as i needed output as

```
Summary 

 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Comment: I don't see how your code relates to machine learning, artificial intelligence, or nlp. You also need to clearly state what your problem is, what your expected output is, and what errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last `elif` to simple `if`

```
    if line.strip() == "Summary":
        copy = True
    elif line.strip() == "Sampler":
        copy = False
    if copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```